# Get a three dimensional array as a parameter and return a three dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, rgb

I have to write a function to_red that should zero out the green and blue color components and return the result. I wrote the below code for an Image(.png) to zero out green and blue color and return red and it worked. However, as mentioned in title, the input parameter has to be a 3-d array and return a 3-d array. How should my below code be changed for that.

```
import numpy as np
```

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
```

def to_red()

```
src = plt.imread("C:\src\painting.png")
```

red_channel = src[:,:,0]

```
red_img = np.zeros(src.shape)
```

red_img[:,:,0] = red_channel

```
plt.imshow(red_img)
```

plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

def to_red(src):
    # Check if the input dimension is 3
    if not src.ndim == 3:
        # Raise exception or do something
        print ("Dimension mismatch")
        return 0

    red_channel = src[:,:,0]
    red_img = np.zeros(src.shape)
    red_img[:,:,0] = red_channel

    return red_img
```

And then you can call it like this

```
source_image = plt.imread("C:\src\painting.png")

red_image = to_red(source_image)

plt.imshow(red_image)    
plt.show()
```

I also added a line to check if the input is actually 3 dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for the help. ...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`'s powerful indexing capabilities

```
def to_red(src):
    ret = a.copy() 
    ret[:,:,1:] = 0 
    return ret
```